# Custom List only showing last added item

Tags: android, android-fragments, custom-lists

My custom list only shows the last retrieved item. Can anyone help?

Custom List's codes:

```
public class CustomList_Events extends ArrayAdapter<Event>{

    private final Activity context;
    private final List<Event> eventsList;

    public CustomList_Events(Activity context, List<Event> eventsList) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_single);
        this.context = context;
        this.eventsList = eventsList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(eventsList.size() <= 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return eventsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Event getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return eventsList.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        //set up the inflater...
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);

        //reference the widgets...
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        TextView txtDate = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        Log.i("CustomList", "Start customList");

        txtTitle.setText(eventsList.get(position).getEvent_title());
        txtDate.setText(eventsList.get(position).getStart_date());
        new GetImageAsyncTask(imageView).execute(Constants.HOST_NAME + "/"+ Constants.CMS_NAME+ "/" +eventsList.get(position).getSmall_picture_path());
        Log.i("Event_CustomList", "Added "+eventsList.get(position).getEvent_title());
        Log.i("CustomList", "End customList");

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Code from the fragment calling it:

```
public static class EventsSectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        SharedPreferences settings = null;
        Editor editor;
        ListView list;
        TextView noEventsTv;

        public EventsSectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            recLifeCycle_with_savedInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events, container, false);

            list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
            noEventsTv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.norecordsTV);



            new GetEventsAsyncTask((MainActivity) getActivity()).execute(nyp.edu.sg.alumnigo.SharedPreferences.getUserName(getActivity()));

            settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

            return rootView;
        }

        public void updateEventList(final List<Event> eventList)
        {

            Log.i("updateEventList:eventlist.count", String.valueOf(eventList.size()));

            if (eventList.size() > 0) 
            {

                Log.i("CustomList", "Start customlist inflation");
                CustomList_Events adapter = new CustomList_Events(getActivity(), eventList);noEventsTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {

                        String eventSel = eventList.get(position).getEvent_id();
                        event_id = eventSel;
                        // direct to event details fragment
                        startEventDetailsFragment();
                    }
                });
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                list.invalidateViews();
            } 
            else 
            {
                noEventsTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
```

Here's the logcat of it:

```
10-13 10:58:51.566: I/CustomList(23269): Start customlist inflation
10-13 10:58:51.586: I/CustomList(23269): Start customList
10-13 10:58:51.596: I/Event_CustomList(23269): Added Home Coming 2014
10-13 10:58:51.596: I/Event_CustomList(23269): Added Talk on Big Data
10-13 10:58:51.596: I/Event_CustomList(23269): Added Breakfast Get-together
10-13 10:58:51.596: I/Event_CustomList(23269): Added SIT Movie Night
10-13 10:58:51.596: I/Event_CustomList(23269): Added 1-Day Durian Trip
10-13 10:58:51.596: I/Events thumbnail(23269): retrieve thumbnail
10-13 10:58:51.596: I/Event_CustomList(23269): Added S.E.A Aquarium
10-13 10:58:51.596: I/CustomList(23269): End customList
10-13 10:58:51.606: I/CustomList(23269): Start customList
10-13 10:58:51.606: I/Event_CustomList(23269): Added Home Coming 2014
10-13 10:58:51.606: I/Event_CustomList(23269): Added Talk on Big Data
10-13 10:58:51.606: I/Event_CustomList(23269): Added Breakfast Get-together
10-13 10:58:51.606: I/Event_CustomList(23269): Added SIT Movie Night
10-13 10:58:51.606: I/Event_CustomList(23269): Added 1-Day Durian Trip
10-13 10:58:51.606: I/Event_CustomList(23269): Added S.E.A Aquarium
10-13 10:58:51.606: I/CustomList(23269): End customList
10-13 10:58:52.046: I/Events thumbnail(23269): retrieve thumbnail
10-13 10:58:52.226: I/Events thumbnail(23269): retrieve thumbnail
10-13 10:58:52.366: I/Events thumbnail(23269): retrieve thumbnail
10-13 10:58:52.486: I/Events thumbnail(23269): retrieve thumbnail
10-13 10:58:52.666: I/Events thumbnail(23269): retrieve thumbnail
10-13 10:58:52.796: I/Events thumbnail(23269): retrieve thumbnail
10-13 10:58:53.016: I/Events thumbnail(23269): retrieve thumbnail
10-13 10:58:53.036: I/CustomList(23269): Start customList
10-13 10:58:53.036: I/Event_CustomList(23269): Added Home Coming 2014
10-13 10:58:53.036: I/Event_CustomList(23269): Added Talk on Big Data
10-13 10:58:53.036: I/Event_CustomList(23269): Added Breakfast Get-together
10-13 10:58:53.036: I/Event_CustomList(23269): Added SIT Movie Night
10-13 10:58:53.036: I/Event_CustomList(23269): Added 1-Day Durian Trip
10-13 10:58:53.036: I/Event_CustomList(23269): Added S.E.A Aquarium
10-13 10:58:53.036: I/CustomList(23269): End customList
```

The result of the custom list

[image: Custom list result]

Am I doing something wrong? Or do I need to add more to my codes?

EDIT:

Here's the async task:

```
public Boolean postData(String user_id) throws JSONException {

    Boolean error = false;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  // specify the URL you want to post to

    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(Constants.HOST_NAME+"/"+Constants.SERVICE_NAME+"/api/Event?userId=" + user_id);
        BufferedReader reader;
        StringBuffer sb;
        String line = "";
        String NL="";
        String json;
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
        {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

             sb = new StringBuffer("");
             line = "";
             NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }

            reader.close();
            json = sb.toString();

            Log.i("event json",json);
            Log.i("Events", "retrieved events");
            try
            {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);   

                for (int i = 0, length = jsonArray.length(); i < length; i++)
                {
                    JSONObject attribute = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Event eventObj =  new Event(); 
                    eventObj.setEvent_id(attribute.getString("event_id"));
                    eventObj.setEvent_title(attribute.getString("event_title"));
                    eventObj.setEvent_desc(attribute.getString("event_desc"));
                    eventObj.setStart_date(attribute.getString("start_date"));
                    eventObj.setEnd_date(attribute.getString("end_date"));
                    eventObj.setStart_time(attribute.getString("start_time"));
                    eventObj.setEnd_time(attribute.getString("end_time"));
                    eventObj.setLocation(attribute.getString("location"));
                    eventObj.setPicture_path(attribute.getString("picture_path"));
                    eventObj.setSmall_picture_path(attribute.getString("small_picture_path"));

                    eventList.add(eventObj);
                    eventObj = null;
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                error = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            error = true;
        }


    } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
    {
        // process execption
        error = true;
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // process execption
        error = true;
    }
    return error;

}
```

and here's the count for the return:

```
10-13 10:58:51.566: I/updateEventList:eventlist.count(23269): 6
```

UPDATE:

As I have seen it, it seems that all my items stack above each other, causing it to only display the last item.

Comment: Please show the code of GetEventsAsyncTask.Add the following code in your getView() method to show your list size:  Log.i("CustomList", "" + getCount());

Comment: change `super call` in adapter `super(context, R.layout.list_single, eventsList);` like this

Comment: @kaushik Sorry, not working. Still shows 1 item. Moreover, it only adds in the 1st item only.

Comment: @AurorerD.Wysteria where you call method updateEventList,

Comment: Within a separate method, after retrieving from server is complete.

Comment: @AurorerD.Wysteria, make sure you didn't gave height of listview as fill_parent of match_parent. if this then you should to change it to wrap_content

Comment: another things may be happened for that case is listview inside scrollview, if this then you should to remove scrollview for this.Also aware scrollview from your main xml view, where you added your fragment contains listview.

Comment: @HashirSheikh my listView is not within a scrollView and it's height is wrap_content.

Comment: I am making a wild guess based on documentation, but you want to try `View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null);`. Don't provide `true` or `false`. Cuz you don't care about what its parent is going to be right?

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. Still the same result @Darpan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within my layout for Custom List, I had a background. After removing it, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this part of your code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    //set up the inflater...
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);

    //reference the widgets...
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    TextView txtDate = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    Log.i("CustomList", "Start customList");

    txtTitle.setText(eventsList.get(position).getEvent_title());
    txtDate.setText(eventsList.get(position).getStart_date());
    new GetImageAsyncTask(imageView).execute(Constants.HOST_NAME + "/"+ Constants.CMS_NAME+ "/" +eventsList.get(position).getSmall_picture_path());
    Log.i("Event_CustomList", "Added "+eventsList.get(position).getEvent_title());
    Log.i("CustomList", "End customList");

    return rowView;
}
```

to this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View rowView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(rowView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
    }

    //reference the widgets...
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    TextView txtDate = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    Log.i("CustomList", "Start customList");

    txtTitle.setText(eventsList.get(position).getEvent_title());
    txtDate.setText(eventsList.get(position).getStart_date());
    new GetImageAsyncTask(imageView).execute(Constants.HOST_NAME + "/"+ Constants.CMS_NAME+ "/" +eventsList.get(position).getSmall_picture_path());
    Log.i("Event_CustomList", "Added "+eventsList.get(position).getEvent_title());
    Log.i("CustomList", "End customList");

    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: @Aurorer D. Wysteria, did you try it?

Comment: It did not work. It only added the first item and repeatedly replaced it with the same item.

Comment: Try  it by replacing rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true); to rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, false);